# Checkout a GitHub repository in Heroku

Tags: node.js, git, github, heroku

My NodeJS website's content comes from a GitHub repository. So I need to checkout the repository while starting the app and read all file content into memory. Also periodically I will try to checkout the repository to see if there are any new commits made. 
I was able to do this in my own server but I am planning to move to Heroku. As Heroku does not have any disk how can I achieve the same in Heroku?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I figured out a solution which works on Heroku using the following steps.

1. I have used https://www.npmjs.com/package/os to get `homedir` folder on Heroku
2. Then used `simple-git` library to clone my repo to the home folder.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: [Download and Install the Heroku CLI](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli#download-and-install).

It uses github "under the hood".

Therefore, you can deploy and clone your Heroku code with commands almost identical to Github commands.

Step 2: Within Heroku, create a new app, give it a name, for example 'myHerokuApp'

Step 3: Login to the Heroku CLI via the command prompt on your local machine:

```
heroku login
```

Step 4: On your local machine, `cd` into your project root directory and run

```
heroku git:remote -a myHerokuApp
```

This will set your local repo to the Heroku app you just created.

The world is now at your fingertips:

**Deploy your app**

```
git add .
git commit -am "make it better"
git push heroku master
```

**To clone the repository**
Use Git to clone your source code to your local machine.

```
heroku git:clone -a myHerokuApp
cd myHerokuApp
```

Once the code is cloned (to any machine that has access to your Heroku CLI), you can view commits by running:

```
git log --pretty=format:"%h %s" --graph
```

[Step by step video tutorial here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XAOvH6yFcz4&t=3s)